# How to update go doc against local file changes?

Tags: go

When I tweak my Go documentation, `go doc` shows the old documentation instead. How do I get `go doc` to update its cache against local file changes?

Comment: The `go doc` command reads the source files on every execution of the command.  There is no cache.  Please show the commands you executed, what you got and what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Strangey, `go doc` presents an abbreviated version of the documentation: Package documentation is included, and public members are listed, but the `go doc` command does not show the documentation for the public members, even with the `-u` option. Instead, the `godoc` tool must be used.

Comment: The `go doc` subcommand and `godoc` are different tools.   Run `go help doc` to learn how to show documentation for exported entities with the `go doc` command.